# Get live data from database in solidity

Tags: sql, reactjs, create-react-app, solidity

I have a token contract in solidity. I want to make mapping `isWhitelisted[msg.sender]`, i figured i should use

[oraclize](http://www.oraclize.it)

for this. How can `isWhitelisted` return true **only** when person wallet is listed on **sql database**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know you can't check it this way. (So far)

But a workaround i am using by my own is using a mapping together with a struct.

```
struct testStruct {
    string test;
    bool isValue;
}

mapping (address => testStruct ) public tests;

// Than you can do

function isWhitelisted() public view returns (bool isValue_)
{
    if (tests[msg.sender].isValue) {
        uniName_ = tests[msg.sender].isValue;
    }
}


// or use it like this

require(tests[msg.sender].isValue);
```

bool isValue is only necessary to check if msg.sender is available in the mapping. I can better help you, if you provide more information on what you have done so far.

**Update**

Example: http://dapps.oraclize.it/browser-solidity/#gist=9817193e5b05206847ed1fcd1d16bd1d&version=soljson-v0.4.21+commit.dfe3193c.js

DieselPrice.sol, simple XML API endpoint: https://www.fueleconomy.gov/ws/rest/fuelprices

```
function __callback(bytes32 myid, string result) {
    if (msg.sender != oraclize_cbAddress()) throw;
    newDieselPrice(result);
    DieselPriceUSD = parseInt(result, 2); // let's save it as $ cents
    // do something with the USD Diesel price
}

function update() payable {
    newOraclizeQuery("Oraclize query was sent, standing by for the answer..");
    oraclize_query("URL", "xml(https://www.fueleconomy.gov/ws/rest/fuelprices).fuelPrices.diesel");
}
```

in __callback the XML element "fuelPrices.diesel" will be saved into the public DieselPriceUSD variable. New example:

```
function __callback(bytes32 myid, bool isWhitelisted ) { // I dont know if type casting is possible this way
    if (msg.sender != oraclize_cbAddress()) throw;
    if (isWhitelisted) {
       callEventXYZ();
    }

}


function checkWhitelist() payable {
    newOraclizeQuery("Oraclize query was sent, standing by for the answer..");
    oraclize_query("URL", "xml(https://YourXMLAPIEndpoint?msgaddress=" + msg.sender +").isWhitelisted.value"); // Or something similar to this
}
```

To concat the msg.sender address into the query url you can check this link:
http://docs.oraclize.it/#ethereum-quick-start

Examples:
strConcat()

```
// Absolute time: get the result from the given datasource at the specified UTC timestamp in the future
oraclize_query(scheduled_arrivaltime+3*3600,
  "WolframAlpha", strConcat("flight ", flight_number, " landed"));
```

OR Post msg.sender as JSON to the API:

```
// The URL datasource also supports a supplement argument, useful for creating HTTP POST requests.
// If that argument is a valid JSON string, it will be automatically sent as JSON.
oraclize_query("URL", "json(https://shapeshift.io/sendamount).success.deposit",
  '{"pair":"eth_btc","amount":"1","withdrawal":"1AAcCo21EUc1jbocjssSQDzLna9Vem2UN5"}')
```

Comment: This code is good, but not quite on point. What i want is to get data directly from sql server, outside contract. Let's say person wants to get whitelisted. He does KYC and is added to sql database. What i want is to look at database from contract and confirm his wallet field matches the query.

Comment: Is't the whitelist information stored on the blockchain itself? Otherwise you maybe can create a web API and access the information with oraclize (as you already mentioned). Examples can be found here: http://dapps.oraclize.it/browser-solidity/#gist=9817193e5b05206847ed1fcd1d16bd1d&version=soljson-v0.4.21+commit.dfe3193c.js

Comment: Yeah, but the point is to let people whitelist themselves, making the process automatic and instant. I saw the oraclize solution, but thought maybe someone provides easy solution for api. Also, way for each individual user to self-whitelist in any other matter would help too. Since blockchain is public and private info shouldn't be leaked in transaction.

Comment: I still dont get the point. Please provide more information about the whole process. Where you want to allow whitelisting people? On a centralized web app with sql based database? The whitelist should not be public ? The API to provide this can be written in many many ways. A more explained example above.

Comment: Thank you, implementing oracles and getting data from databese and JSON helped